# Find the length of a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a way to efficiently find the number of lines in a text file. I am iterating through files, but each file has a different number of lines.

```
with open(filename) as fin:
for line in islice(fin, 5, 100000000):    
    lines.append(line)
```

Instead of putting a huge number to make sure I include all the lines, is there a better way to read how many lines are in the file?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem to me. Rather than asking "how do I find the number of lines in a file?", you ought to be asking "how do I slice five lines off the start of a file iterator without having to specify a `stop` value?"

Comment: Hey, @Kevin: do you think I should re-open?

Comment: count the number of line breaks